# Change color of DrawerToggle in toolbar on Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-styles

Can anybody pinpoint why my drawer toggle (the little hamburger icon that animates to open the navigation drawer) refuses to switch color on me? It's causing me a lot of downtime and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's my theme - the drawer toggle takes on the color of disabled_default_text.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MyApp.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/cs7</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/disabled_default_text</item>
</style>
```

And here's the toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/ab_solid"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
    app:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"/>
```

MyToolbarTheme - where I overwrite colorControlNormal with the color white.

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme"     parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

What's odd is that adding colorControlNormal changes the color of the overflow menu from the disabled_default_text color to white, but the drawer toggle doesn't get changed. Can anybody figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's `Widget.MyApp.ActionBar`? It would help if you would create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

You can add `drawerArrowStyle`to your theme as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>
```

and you can customize your `MyDrawerArrowToggle` as

```
 <style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

proof this:

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/theme_wbackground</item>
</style>
```

style-v21.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/theme_wbackground</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_primary</item>
</style>
```

and int Toolbar:
app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/theme_primary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions are using style that's probably gonna work.But what if you want to replace it with your icon.Hope this will help to someone.

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

mToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); // this is very important don't miss it
mToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_logo); // here your logo
```

When you enable drawer indicator you lose listener for click of toggle that's why you have to handle it by yourself.

```
mToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }
});
```

That's it happy coding:)